# Blank variables and INT columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in a table which is has the data type of an integer. What I had in mind was that values added into that column will be either 0 - N, or just blank as in an empty variable (see below), but I'm not sure that this is possible?

```
if($resource) {
   $resource = $id - 2;
} else {
   $resource = "";
}

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (...,resource,...) VALUES (...,'$resource',...)");
```

If not, could I instead use the data type of VARCHAR, and then say:

```
if($resource) {
   $resource = $id - 2;
} else {
   $resource = "INVALID";
}
```

In that case, is there any conversion functions I'd have to do when extracting values from the column `resource`, or would numbers automatically be treated as integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the field should be "white" for any reason, I think you should mark it as NULLABLE and use word NULL (not INVALID)

If a column is a number, **never** use a varchar, you will loose a lot of things (also, an int is smaller than a varchar)

**EDIT 1:** Code snippet to allow null values on column:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn INT;
```

If you specify it as:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn INT NOT NULL;
```

It will be not nullable, so it should be nullable by default if you didn't declare it differently

**EDIT 2:** Important note, the column **must not be UNIQUE** otherwise the value will be not nullable!

Comment: So I can still set the column to `INT` but use NULL as the value in place of `""` or `"INVALID`?

Comment: Yes, but you must set the database column as nullable. NULL shouldn't be quoted also (is a special value). I forgot, columns are nullable by default, you just have to avoid to set it as NOT NULL.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, made it a lot more clear :). It's not a UNIQUE column and "Null" has been set to `null` in PhpMyAdmin (default there is `not null`), so it should be all good.